# how to detect if browser is firefox with php?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any php code to detect the browser with version and operating system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142030/any-php-code-to-detect-the-browser-with-version-and-operating-system)
>   [how to detect internet explorer and firefox using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702667/how-to-detect-internet-explorer-and-firefox-using-php)

I need to add specific html to non firefox browsers, therefore I need to first detect if user is using firefox or not, i have to do this using php. Something along these line?

```
<!--[if Firefox]>
Mozilla only HTML here!
<![endif]-->
```

Any one? Thanks

Comment: By the way, the example you gave is conditional HTML comment, not PHP.

Comment: Sorry, completely missed those posts. Yes, I am aware that html, it was just a quick example, can't i do it using plain html conditionals btw?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use this snippet of code to retrieve the kind of browser:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
}
```

Then, compare against the user agent string.

For example, to detect "Firefox" you could do:

```
if (strlen(strstr($agent, 'Firefox')) > 0) {
    $browser = 'firefox';
}
```

Comment: what should i write as "HTTP_USER_AGENT" ? firefox, FIREFOX, Firefox, mozilla, MOZILLA, Mozilla, gecko, GECKO, Gecko?

Comment: so:

if(strlen(strstr($agent,"Firefox")) > 0 ){ 

  $browser = 'firefox';
  do something...

} else { do something else };

?

Comment: Yes. If you detect that is firefox the user agent, let's insert the snippet of code you have to insert into html (by appending it? could be a solution)

Comment: You can just use strpos, which is way much faster than your unnecessary strlen and strstr.

Answer (score 2):

php's inbuilt function get_browser  is your answer. or try using $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] or simply use this script http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php/

Answer (score 1):

Use the get_browser function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Comment: To use this, you need to have `browscap.ini` set up on your system.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `User-Agent` header in the request. Either you do a regex check on it to find Firefox specific patterns or you can use a library like WURFL that has a better chance of identifying the browser.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6127519/182629) for an example on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] to get user browser.

Answer (score 0):

look in `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`

e.g.: `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:13.0a1) Gecko/20120206 Firefox/13.0a1`

Comment: Some browsers send the wrong strings. maybe you should tell him what string to look for?